# Round off to 10's

Tags: python, rounding

I'm a beginner to Python. I want to make the code round off to every 10's, ex. from 33 to 30.

### Here's the code so far:

```
def roundoff(a, b):
    b = round(b)
    print str(a) + " you are around " + str(b) + " years old."

>>> roundoff("Bob", 33)
Bob you are around 33.0 years old.
```

---

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Define your own function:

```
def my_round(x):
    return x - (x % 10) #or py2.x: (b/10)*10, py3.x: (b//10)*10
... 
>>> my_round(33)
30
>>> my_round(333)
330
```

Use string formatting instead of using concatenation and `str()` conversions:

```
>>> def roundoff(a, b):
...        b = b - (b % 10)
...        print "{} you are around {} years old.".format(a, b)
...     
>>> roundoff('bob', 33)
bob you are around 30 years old.
>>> roundoff('bob', 97)
bob you are around 90 years old.
```

Comment: I like this answer, but what if the OP wanted to round up for 97?  It's not clear from the question, but it might be interesting to see how the algorithm would differ.

Comment: @SethMMorton Then we can use: `int(round(97/10.0)*10)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like:

```
def roundoff(name,age):
   age = age - age%10 #the % operator will get the rest of the division by 10 
                      #(so from 33 will get 3)
   print str(name) + " you are around " + str(age) + " years old."
```

Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def roundoff(name, age):
    print '%s, you are around %d years old.' % (name, (age /10) * 10)
```

When the `/` operator is dividing int by int it returns another int. So when you are dividing 33 by 10, the result will be 3 and not 3.3. After this you just have to multiply the result by 10.